# Index find position for matching string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Consider following example

```
index_abcd = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index_abcd)
index_id= df.index
```

I want to find the position of 'a' in the index "index_id". How do I do that. Trying

```
index_id.index('a')
```

does not work (error 'Index' object has no attribute 'index'). Thanks a lot

Comment: You could try `enumerate()`, like `[i for i, x in enumerate(index_id) if x == 'a']`. But this approach doesn't seem to be optimal if the list gets too big

Comment: you use a class Index, it's no longer a string, there is no index attribute. You should have a look to the class to see if there is another attribute you could use. maybe 'data'. You may try index_id.data.index('a') as data is a 1 dimension array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to type :

```
index_id.get_loc("a")
```

Comment: Same here: Thanks, works. Unfortunately I can only give one check for good answer. (above)

Comment: Mine is one line code :), I'm kidding, most important is that you get the answer you want !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
index = pd.Index(list(df))
print index.get_loc('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you want:

```
print(df.ix['a'].index.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[0]
```